# Remove certain rows from dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                        date         col_1    col_2
(exchange, symbol)
 CME,abc                2015-01-02   435      5678
                        2015-01-03   754      236
 JSE,xyz                2015-01-02   15       6871
                        2015-01-03   7258     7236
```

There is a multi-index which is exchange + symbol. I need to remove all rows for a specific index. eg: remove all (CME,abc) rows.

Usually when I need to remove rows based on a condition I would do something like this:

```
df = df[df['col_1'] != 754]
```

However this seems to only work for basing row removals on a specific column condition. What I need to do is the same thing, but based on a certain index.

Comment: It looks like you have a MultiIndex - is "date" part of the index too?

Comment: Hi. I updated the original question to show exactly what my index looks like. I was originally just using a simplified version. But no, date is not part of the multi-index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the label you want to remove with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). In case of a multi-index, you can pass the label as a tuple.
Using a dummy example:

```
In [46]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,2), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],[1,1,2,2]]))

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
            0         1
a 1  0.510701  0.534342
  1  0.229360 -1.403280
b 2 -0.218433  0.619108
  2 -0.679179 -0.195241

In [48]: df.drop([('a', 1)])
Out[48]:
            0         1
b 2 -0.218433  0.619108
  2 -0.679179 -0.195241
```

By the way, you can apply your logic of `df[df['col_1'] != 754]` also on the index. This would give `df[df.index != 754]`, although this would not work with a multi-index

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a tuple of your index labels to `drop`

```
In [117]:
df1.drop(('CME','abc'))

Out[117]:
                      date  col_1  col_2
exchange symbol                         
JSE      xyz    2015-01-02     15   6871
         xyz    2015-01-03   7258   7236
```